# Bumblebee stopped working after the today's update

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, bumblebee

I've followed [this guide](http://www.muktware.com/2013/12/install-nvidia-331-bumblebee-optimus-cards/18271) to put Bumblebee to work. Everything was working perfect and I was happy playing my Steam games using primusrun to run them. But after today's update, which updated something related to NVIDIA, Bumblebee is not working anymore:

```
$ primusrun glxgears
2014/06/01 02:36:36 socat[4154] E connect(3, AF=1 "/var/run/bumblebee.socket", 27): No such file or directory
primus: fatal: failed to connect to Bumblebee daemon: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I have an optimus notebook with a dedicated Nvidia GeForce 730M and an integrated Intel card. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by reinstalling *bbswitch-dkms*. I guess that when a NVIDIA related package was updated in the main repositories, something on the kernel was changed. So, reinstalling *bbswitch-dkms* fixed the primusrun problem. All I had to do was to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bbswitch-dkms
```

I hope it helps someone who is having the same problem I had. Now *primusrun* works again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu 15.10 and unfortunately this didn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, after looking over the link you supplied, and doing some digging of my own, I've found this link that should get you going.
Excerpt from link:

> *SOLUTION: Replace all the *-bumblebee packages by * packages, this means enabling multiverse repo and drawing all of it from official repos instead of anything from AUR. Examples: nvidia instead of nvidia-bumblebee, primus instead of primus-git, nvidia-utils instead of nvidia-utils-bumblebee, lib32-nvidia-utils instead of lib32-nvidia-utils-bumblebee. Some time ago the 'official' instructions were exactly the other way round, but it seems this was now completely reverted.*

Source link: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162219

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I never installed these packages in the first place. I installed bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia and primus from ppa:bumblebee/stable and I installed nvidia-331 and nvidia-settings-331 from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa. Anyway, I managed to fix the problem by reinstalling bbswitch-dkms. I'll post a more detailed answer to tell what I did.